# why image is shown blur while preview?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image-uploading

I am using the below plugin to upload an image 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-file-upload

but when I choose an image it show blur image why ?

here is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/ujnmzf8e/1/

```
.thumb {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: How big is the original image? Looks like you're stretching the image

Comment: you can use any image.image is too big

Comment: why image strech ?

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the image and set the quality of the photo like this I went ahead and deleted your thumb class. Also, the link to the documentation is here.[NgUploadFeatures](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#features)

```
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Upload on form submit</legend>
  Username:

  <input ngf-resize="{width: 100, height: 100, quality: .8, type: 'image/jpeg',  centerCrop: true, pattern='.jpg', restoreExif: true}" type="file" ngf-select ng-model="picFile" name="file"    
         accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" required
         ngf-model-invalid="errorFile">
  <i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.required">*required</i><br>
  <i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.maxSize">File too large 
      {{errorFile.size / 1000000|number:1}}MB: max 2M</i>
  <img   ng-show="myForm.file.$valid" ngf-thumbnail="picFile" > <button ng-click="picFile = null" ng-show="picFile">Remove</button>
  <br>
  <button ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid" 
          ng-click="uploadPic(picFile)">Submit</button>
  <span class="progress" ng-show="picFile.progress >= 0">
    <div style="width:{{picFile.progress}}%" 
        ng-bind="picFile.progress + '%'"></div>
  </span>
  <span ng-show="picFile.result">Upload Successful</span>
  <span class="err" ng-show="errorMsg">{{errorMsg}}</span>
</fieldset>
```